# How to instantly write sql query output table to csv in Python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database

I have written a sql query:

```
SELECT a,b
from db
```

I use library psycopg2 to connect to database. Then I can use pandas.io.sql to write table to pandas dataframe. But the problem is that this dataframe is too large (over 1.5 billion rows) and I can't open it in Jupyter. How could I instantly write output as csv?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to go through Pandas. Recognize that a .csv file is just a text file, where in the first row you have the column headers, and then in each row you have the values for these headers, separated by comma. Therefore, you can just take response from your DB query and write it to a file and save it.